# ionic back button showing not properly

Tags: ionic-framework, back-button

i try to show a back button to switch between my components.
To do so i created this header:

```
<ion-header translucent >
  <ion-toolbar >
   <ion-buttons slot="start">
  <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
</ion-buttons>
<ion-title>Registrieren</ion-title>
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content >
  <form [formGroup]="authdetails" >
   <ion-item >
    <ion-label  position="floating">E-Mail</ion-label>
   <ion-input  formControlName="email" type="email"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
<ion-item >
  <ion-label position="floating">Nutzername</ion-label>
  <ion-input  formControlName="nickname"  type="email"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item >
  <ion-label position="floating">Passwort</ion-label>
  <ion-input formControlName="pw"  type="password"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<br>
<ion-item lines="none">
  <ion-label >Hiermit bestätige ich den <a href="https://eatsmartapp.de/datenschutzerklaerung-app/">Datenschutz</a></ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox  slot="start" formControlName="privacy"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
<ion-item lines="none">
  <ion-label >Hiermit bestätige ich die <a href="https://eatsmartapp.de/anb-endverbraucher/">AGB's </a></ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox slot="start" formControlName="agb"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
</form>
<div align="center">
<button class="button register" 
  (click)="performRegister()">Registrieren</button>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

The way i'm routing to this view is like i did here:

```
      <button class="button register" routerLink="/register">Kostenlos Registrieren</button>
```

The problem is that the back button is showed really small, please find attached a screenshot:

[image: back button]

Comment: Could you post your complete HTML file where this is an issue?

Comment: here you go :). I hope you can find the mistake